# C# Get values from html

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have this html

```html
     <a class="video" style="display: block" href="some text">
                            <img class="pic" src="" alt="">
                            <div class="title">some text</div>
                    </a>
    
    <a class="video" style="display: block" href="some text">
                            <img class="pic" src="" alt="">
                            <div class="title">some text</div>
                    </a>
```

It goes down multiple times. How can I get the values from `href` and the titles?

I tried this but I couldn't figure how to get `<div class="title">`

```cs
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='video']")) 
{ 
Console.WriteLine("node:" + node.GetAttributeValue("href", null));
}
```

Comment: have you ***tried anything yet***?

Comment: i tried this but i couldnt figure how to get <div class="title">                                               
   foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='video']"))
            {

              Console.WriteLine("node:" + node.GetAttributeValue("href", null));

Comment: What do you mean by "It goes down multiple times"? Do you mean you have repeated the same code block multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```cs
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='video']")) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("href: " + node.GetAttributeValue("href", null));
    Console.WriteLine("title: " + node.SelectSingleNode("./div[@class='title']").InnerText);
}
```